# Modifying a function to return username correctly, for a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two Wordpress Plugins and both authors of the plugins refuse to admit the clash/issue is their site but it's quite clear that both parties can fix the issue very easily.

I provided one plugin author with the fix that has no negative impact on their plugin in any way, it doesn't cause any problems if the person has the second plugin installed or not but they won't add the fix to their plugin even though it adds compatibility with a different plugin.

I am unable to work out how to fix the second plugin, but I know what needs to be done...

## Snippet from Plugin 1 (One that I provided a fix to)

```
/* check if the user is valid */
if ( true === wlm_admin_in_admin() || true === $special_bypass ) {
    $validuser = username_exists( $data['username'] );

    if ( ! $validuser ) {
        $validuser        = email_exists( $data['email'] );
        $user_info        = get_userdata( $validuser );
        $data['username'] = $user_info->user_login;
    }

    $data['password'] = __( 'Already assigned', 'wishlist-member' );
} else {
    $validuser = wp_login( $data['username'], $data['password'] );
}
if ( $validuser ) {
    $user      = $this->Get_UserData( 0, $data['username'] );
    /* check for blacklist status */
    $blacklist = $this->CheckBlackList( $user->user_email );
}
```

Now, if find the line:

```
$validuser = wp_login( $data['username'], $data['password'] );
```

And replace it with:

```
//$validuser = wp_login( $data['username'], $data['password'] );
$tmpvaliduser = username_exists( $data['username'] );
if ($tmpvaliduser)
    $validuser = wp_login( $data['username'], $data['password'] );

if ( ! $validuser || !$tmpvaliduser) {     
    if((!$data['email'])  && !(false === strrpos($data['username'], "@")) ) {
        $validuser        = email_exists( $data['username'] );
        $user_info        = get_userdata( $validuser );
        $data['username'] = $user_info->user_login;
        $validuser = wp_login( $data['username'], $data['password'] );  
    }     
}
```

Then this fixes the issue because it changes the `$data['username']` variable to their actual username which means the rest of the plugin 1 will continue correctly and bind certain details to the username (account) rather than a username consisting of their email (which obviously doesn't exist as a username)

- If username exists (they tried to login with username & password) then it continues like normal.
- If username does NOT exist then it checks if the email exists instead, if it does then it will grab the username from the email address that was entered and simply changes the entered username field with their actual username instead of their email and then continues like normal

## Snippet from Plugin 2 (One that I need a fix for)

```
function email_login_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) )
        return $user;
    if ( !empty( $username ) ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );
        if ( isset( $user, $user->user_login, $user->user_status ) && 0 == (int) $user->user_status ) {
            $username = $user->user_login;
        }
        $result = wp_authenticate_username_password( null, $username, $password );
        if (is_a ( $result, 'WP_User' ) ) {
            global $WishListMemberInstance;
            $WishListMemberInstance->WPMAutoLogin($user->ID);
            $_POST['log'] = $username;
            $WishListMemberInstance->Login();
        }
    }
    return wp_authenticate_username_password( null, $username, $password );
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what the above snippit does in full, but I understand it good enough and I need to change it so that it **returns the correct username** **somehow so that `$data['username']` is replaced with the username** instead of the email (if an email is used)

Comment: according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login `wp_login()` is deprecated. It has been deprecated for a long time now. Combine this circumstantial evidence with Plugin1 author's attitude, maybe it's time to stop using that plugin.

Comment: @JamesJones Being that the `wp_login()` function isn't in the deprecated list of functions, I would assume they've removed `wp_login()` fully from 4.4.1 and that the plugin author has created their own custom `wp_login()` function. To be fair to Plugin 1 their Wordpress & their plugin don't advertise ability to login with email so it's not really for them to fix. Instead the Plugin 2 author should fix it as it's their plugin that has the fault.

Comment: I can't move away from that plugin at the moment, I have too many plugins that do things with the main plugin and would need to recode loads.

Comment: Ryflex, I would not assume that "wp_login" is a custom function written by the plugin author unless I saw the declaration!

Comment: What are the actual plugins we're looking at here?

Comment: It would help if you can provide the context of how you use the code from the second snippet and where you expect using the username, so we can figure a way of doing this without having to make changes in plugin code.

Comment: What is the problem, and what are you trying to accomplish? No one is answering because the question is extremely vaugue.

Comment: Couldn't you simply update Plugin 1 locally? If the plugin updates you'd have to fix it again, but you could bypass updates for it. Or create a fork of it.

Comment: @sricks Of course he could but that wouldn't be efficient would it, especially if it updates often.

Comment: `function get_user_by( $field, $value ) {
 $userdata = WP_User::get_data_by( $field, $value );

 if ( !$userdata )
  return false;

 $user = new WP_User;
 $user->init( $userdata );

 return $user;
}`  from https://wpseek.com/function/get_user_by/ might be part of the problem in that it doesn't appear to have `$username ` as an email address https://wpseek.com/function/get_user_by_email/ is deprecated but at least does include an email address. Sorry for code in comment and will try to put together as an answer if you think it might be on the right track.

Comment: What do you see if you echo `$username` at various parts of the function? `wp_login` is a core function which might be able to be replaced with https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login `wp_signon()`  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon

Comment: I haven't worked with the plugin before and don't have a quick fix, but since OP seems unable to disclose the plugin name I'll take a stab - It seems to be one (or two) of [WishList Products](http://wishlistproducts.com/)' membership plugins, based on `'wishlist-member'` from the first snippet and `global $WishListMemberInstance;` from the second.

Answer (score 1):

First, my wordpress version

```
Name        : wordpress                    Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 4.4                               Vendor: Fedora Project
Release     : 1.el6                         Build Date: Wed 09 Dec 2015 11:40:49 AM EST
```

plugins on my centos6.4 would be installed at this location:

```
/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins
```

Please pay attention that this function(on my system) not always return a user, WP_Error as well

```
/**
 * Authenticate the user using the username and password.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @param WP_User|WP_Error|null $user     WP_User or WP_Error object from a previous callback. Default null.
 * @param string                $username Username for authentication.
 * @param string                $password Password for authentication.
 * @return WP_User|WP_Error WP_User on success, WP_Error on failure.
 */
function wp_authenticate_username_password($user, $username, $password) {
```

The wp-email-login I found might fit for you:

http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-email-login/trunk/email-login.php

To be more clear, The snippet from plugin 2, should be changed to:

```
function email_login_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) )
        return $user;
    if ( !empty( $username ) ) {


        // add this line to format email - propose change #1
            $username = str_replace( '&', '&amp;', stripslashes( $username ) );
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );
        if ( isset( $user, $user->user_login, $user->user_status ) && 0 == (int) $user->user_status ) {
            $username = $user->user_login;
        }
        $result = wp_authenticate_username_password( null, $username, $password );
        if (is_a ( $result, 'WP_User' ) ) {
            // These 4 lines came from plugin2 from your system, keep as is
            global $WishListMemberInstance;
            $WishListMemberInstance->WPMAutoLogin($user->ID);
            $_POST['log'] = $username;
            $WishListMemberInstance->Login();
        }


        // no need to authenticate another time, return - proposed change #2
        // authenticate twice could be a problem as well
        return $result;
    }
    return wp_authenticate_username_password( null, $username, $password );
}
```